# Which is the best Ubuntu Flavor for an old laptop?

Tags: distro-recommendation

I have a very old Toshiba laptop. Specs can be found [here](http://uk.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/jsp/SUPPORTSECTION/discontinuedProductPage.do?PRODUCT_ID=82136&DISC_MODEL=1&service=UK).

What would be the best distribution for this machine? Does anyone have some suggestions?
I only have 512 MB of RAM.