# Which ubuntu to use for my old laptop?

Tags: lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the best Ubuntu Flavor for an old laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50181/which-is-the-best-ubuntu-flavor-for-an-old-laptop)

I am totally new to Linux. I downloaded ubuntu 12.04 and installed it on my old laptop with 512MB ram, 1.66 ghz processor on a partition of size 10GB( with windows xp on another partition.) Now when I boot to linux it shows Lubuntu at the start screen(which i found out is a lighter version or something, may be because of low specs) .

Now when I run ubuntu and try to browse 5-6 tabs on firefox it starts getting sluggish. Do I need to switch to an older version of Ubuntu or is there any other fix to this??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No that's normal considering your hardware.

Comment: BTW, there's something odd. You say you downloaded Ubuntu but then see Lubuntu? What exactly did you download and from where?

Answer (score 1):

That is because of you low RAM. Starting tab of firfox takes 100-150mb. From second onwards it takes addition 50-75mb RAM. You have a low RAM. Shortage of RAM causes this problem. You can overcome this by assigning a new Swap area. This can be better explained in [this link.](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space)

Comment: Hmm.. I have allocated a swap space of 1GB as of now.. will increase it to 2 and try again.. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're correct that low RAM is the likeliest source of sluggishness, but increasing swap is not a solution (upvoted you anyways). Adding more RAM, or using a browser with smaller memory footprint (some suggestions to try: `midori`, `epiphany` or even `chromium`).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 uses Unity as  the Desktop Environment (DE). **With your 512 ram you should use ONLY Lubuntu which uses LXDE as DE.** It is the lightest of the Ubuntu family. (See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/178112/47206).)

But the fact that it shows Lubuntu at the start screen might not mean necessarily  that you are logging into the LXDE/Lubuntu desktop. It happened to me to see the Lubuntu screen when I chose no matter what DE. So be sure that is LXDE/Lubuntu you chose upon logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
- Ubuntu with low-end customization:lightDM, ubuntu-2D, no effect
- Lubuntu
- Xubuntu

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get it... are these different flavors of ubuntu??

Comment: Yes, Lubuntu is the lightest flavor.

Comment: kind of ... they are actually different GUI's for your linux/ubuntu machine!