# Lubuntu vs. lubuntu-desktop

Tags: lubuntu

I've heard that Lubuntu consumes less resources than Ubuntu. Is it because of the fact that Lubuntu uses different desktop environment and window manager?

If so, would it be equivalent to install `lubuntu-desktop` on top of Ubuntu rather than doing a fresh install?

Comment: depends on the applications you use in Lubuntu-desktop.

Comment: `apt-get -s install lubuntu-desktop` will simulate what will be installed as a result of running the actual command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly.

Lubuntu is essentially Ubuntu, but with a different window manager / graphical shell ([LXDE](http://lxde.org/)) and a different selection of default applications. For example, the default word processing tool is the lightweight, but powerful abiword rather than LibreOffice Writer, gnumeric instead of LibreOffice Calc, audacious for playing music etc.

You can achieve most of that just by changing the selection of installed software and selecting a session type from the login screen, but installing lubuntu-desktop will simplify this task. Moreover, as far as I understand it, installing lubuntu-desktop will not break your regular Ubuntu installation, you will be able to either use your regular Ubuntu desktop as well or remove lubuntu completely.

Comment: Not exactly. If you're using Ubuntu and then install `lubuntu-desktop` you will not have the same lightest experience as if you installed Lubuntu first, because some auto launched process that are used on Ubuntu will be running together, and this process are not used in the original Lubuntu. (For example Zeitgeist that is not used on Lubuntu)

Answer (score 7):

**The main difference is in the desktop environment (DE) and not in the installed applications.**

(The main applications like **Libre office** suite and **Firefox** and **Chromium** internet browsers act ok in LXDE on computers that otherwise cannot cope with Ubuntu/Unity).

People say 'Ubuntu' to refer to the main Ubuntu release which uses **Unity** as DE.

Ubuntu-proper = Ubuntu OS + Gnome/Unity DE

Kubuntu = Ubuntu OS + KDE

Xubuntu = Ubuntu OS + Xfce DE

Lubuntu = Ubuntu OS + LXDE

(More [here](http://cipricuslinux.blogspot.fr/p/what-is-ubuntu-kubuntu-xubuntu-lubuntu.html).)

The difference in resources used by **Unity** compared to **LXDE** is **huge** (from the point of view of my 1GB RAM PC).

**LXDE/Lubuntu** is the lightest, but it takes some more customization to make it look stylish (like [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JUz1qvjJ7gU/UDIuW-sZmAI/AAAAAAAAAd4/Ztlq7wHhzIc/s1600/2012-08-20_48.png)). (It's easy in fact.)

**Xfce/Xubuntu** is a bit heavier, but still light, **KDE/Kubuntu** is close to **Gnome/Unity** in the use of resources, the later being the heaviest.

For example I have a computer that is sluggish in KDE and Unity but works ok in Xfce/Xubuntu and is perfect in LXDE/Lubuntu.

You can install all the different DE that make up the Ubuntu family, try them, and then stuck to the one that best meets your needs and your computer's specs, but having them together is not very useful on the long run.

I have used Lubuntu on top of Xubuntu with no problems and do not think would be any problem to put it on top of Ubuntu-proper. In fact, a fresh install of Lubuntu would mean less stuff installed initially, that you could add afterwards anyway (like Libre Office for example). It all depends on your needs.

Comment: The screenshot is just amazing!

Comment: iconset: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Khq82LxTxnQ/UDIxR22lBCI/AAAAAAAAAeE/J2JVFsQzsi8/s320/customize+look.png, desktop background: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-VIuzJuqIwGI/UDIxUD2TvkI/AAAAAAAAAeM/nQgjxWBqVGY/s320/customize+look2.png. I also use the 'elegant brit' Openbox theme and 'Turquoise nights' window border. In case you select LXDE I can advise on specific tweaks regarding appearance and more.

Comment: Sure! I'm downloading Lubuntu and can't wait to mess up with the themes.

Comment: cool. if you dislike orange in elegant brit theme i just found a blue version https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111040

Comment: @cipricus any hints how to get to the customized theme you've tailored? It looks really nice

Comment: @Thomas - this is an old post now -- cannot say more than what is provided in the posted links; sorry