# What does it mean that Lubuntu and Ubuntu Precise Pangolin have different "Supported until" dates?

Tags: lubuntu

Ubuntu and Lubuntu have different "Supported until" dates for Precise Pangolin (since Ubuntu have LTS releases, but Lubuntu does not).

What exactly does this mean, for me as a user, **if I have Lubuntu installed,** given that both distros use the same apt repository? – Will I not get security updates for Lubuntu-related packages after April 2013? If so, which packages are those? Or are there any other consequences?

P.S. [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Releases) Precise Pangolin is supported until April 2017, while [Lubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu#Releases) Precise Pangolin is supported until October 2013.

**EDIT: Added the bold text.**

**EDIT 2**: I'm wondering what updates etc. I'll get be on a Lubuntu system after October 2013. (Given that both distros use the same apt repo, and that apt repo will continue to be updated until mainline Ubuntu is no longer supported, in April 2017.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu and Lubuntu share the same software repositories. The main difference between Ubuntu and Lubuntu is that Ubuntu installs the package `ubuntu-desktop`, while Lubuntu installs the package `lubuntu-desktop`, with all dependencies that entails.

In fact, you can even install one atop the other, e.g., in an Ubuntu system, issue the command `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` and you will end up with a "hybrid" system with both the Ubuntu packages and the Lubuntu packages, e.g., both Unity and LXDE. (Also see [Lubuntu vs. lubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178026/lubuntu-vs-lubuntu-desktop))

Now, clearly, the lion share of the base system is exactly the same. So even though Lubuntu 12.04 is supported only through October 2013, as the Ubuntu 12.04 repos will be maintained through April 2017, you will also receive many package updates on Lubuntu 12.04.

I guess that what will not be maintained is only some Lubuntu-specific development, as well as support from the Lubuntu team. You can start [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Developers) for an overview of what development is specific to Lubuntu.

Please note that I do not want to encourage using a Lubuntu version that has reached its end of life. I'm just saying there will be many package updates still. :)

Answer (score 4):

Lubuntu 12.04 it's NOT the LTS and it will come to an EOL like the rest of non-LTS releases. Trusty Tahr 14.04 will be the first Lubuntu LTS release with five years of support.

**From official website dedicated to Lubuntu documentation.**

Please note that Lubuntu 12.04 is not an LTS (5 years support), but a `standard` release, supported for 18 months. This is simply due the fact there is insufficient 'man-power' to commit to 5 years of support.

*You will receive updates for 5 years, yet not for all of your packages including LXDE.

(for example packages by Canonical or Ubuntu One Team: Ubuntu One or Firefox won't be updated for Lubuntu) Yet if you curious about every single package, when you'll be on Lubuntu run:

```
apt-cache show packagename | grep ^Supported
```

and you'll see if it's supported yet or not on your current system.

P.S.

And it's actually 12.10 that is still supported. And Ubuntu 12.10 comes to an EOL this April 2014 and 12.10 it's not LTS either. And no you will not get support, fixes, security updates for an EOL version of Ubuntu/Xubuntu/Lubuntu etc...

Comment: Good to know, but that does not even attempt to answer my question.

Comment: see my edited answer :-)

Comment: are you using actually Lubuntu 12.04? because it's 2014 already actually and Lubuntu 12.04 is already an EOL version, as I said it's treated the same way as to non-LTS releases no fixes for kernel, security updates whatsoever.

Comment: you can still use it though but it won't get newer updates as Ubuntu 12.04 will.

Comment: @JohnnyD. As far as I am aware, Ubuntu and Lubuntu use the same software repos. The main difference is that Ubuntu installs the package `ubuntu-desktop`, while Lubuntu installs the package `lubuntu-desktop`, with all dependencies that entails. But, since the repos are the same for Ubuntu and Lubuntu, and since the  Ubuntu 12.04 repos will be maintained through April 2017, you will receive *some* package updates on Lubuntu 12.04. The question is whether some packages, say for instance `lxde`, will remain updated. So the question *which packages* on Lubuntu 12.04 will be maintained is justified.

Comment: yes I agree but still it's not the LTS release :-)

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa If you post that as a separate answer, I'll accept it.