# Which Ubuntu distribution should I install on this laptop?

Tags: system-installation

My laptop has 1GB of RAM and an Intel Pentium processor.  Which distribution would be  best for it?

Specs are [here](http://latestprice.in/hcl-laptop-hcl-me-icon-l-74-a-price-in-india-features-specifications/).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50181/which-is-the-best-ubuntu-flavor-for-an-old-laptop

Comment: I would recommend asking this question on [Unix and Linux Stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), they are more likely to be aware of the differences between Linux distributions.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome in Ubuntu Community :) Because your laptop can have only up to 1 GB memory I suggest you to go with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Long Time Support) 32 bit or 12.10 32 bit. Is should work out of the box. You can download it here:  [http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

It's important that you will install 32 bit version. You can  find some discussion about 32 and 64 bit architecture here.

- [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Comment: While I don't think he would gain anything from installing a 64 bit kernel/distribution, the processor does appear to be 64 bit capable and can handle either.

Answer (score 1):

With just 1Gb of Ram I would go with Lubuntu or maybe Xubuntu.

However it seems you have a display driver problem. Try a liveDVD or liveUSB to make sure everything works before installing.